# How to alter elements with conditionals? Example provided

Tags: javascript

on the assignment, we are pretending to be web designers for a client. Currently, on one of the pages, they have a "more" feature so you can continue reading the paragraph. They now want us to collapse the text and create a "less" feature. They added that we should be using the JavaScript and code that they provided.

I'm not sure how to format this code and how to use each of them to create this "less" feature on the paragraphs.

```
if ( condition ) {
  action
} else {
  alternative_action
}
```

```
$("#q1 .less").removeClass("hidden");
$("#q1 .more").addClass("hidden");
```

Comment: put one jqueeery fragment in `action` and something else in `alternative_action`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've got 2 divs, 1 with class 'more' and the other with 'less' and you need to swap between them, I'd suggest something like this:

```js
if($('#q1 .less').hasClass('hidden')){ // check if the 'less' item is already hidden
  $('#q1 .less').removeClass('hidden'); // show less and hide more
  $('#q1 .more').addClass('hidden');
}else {
  $('#q1 .more').removeClass('hidden'); // show more and hide less
  $('#q1 .less').addClass('hidden');
}
```

See https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/, https://api.jquery.com/addclass/ and https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/ for information about the jQuery functions used.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! There is no div tag under the HTML that they already provided for the assignment. I did swap out the <p class = tag that contained 'more' and 'less' and I reloaded the webpage and it worked. Not sure if that's correct but I ran the code and it said no errors...